# Looking for an error in a simple proof

Tags: proof-verification

> Assume n is an integer. If the square root of $n$ is rational, prove that $n$ is a perfect square.

To prove the above statement, I used a trick rather than the standard way of using the unique factorization theorem over the field of integers. My professor claims that my proof is wrong but I don't know where it went wrong. The proof is as follows:

If $\sqrt{n}$ is rational, then there exists integers $p,q$ with $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ such that $\sqrt{n} = \dfrac{p}{q}$.Therefore by multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{n}$ I obtain $n = \dfrac{p}{q}\sqrt{n}$ or $\sqrt{n} =\dfrac{q *n}{p}$. Since $\sqrt{n} = \dfrac{p}{q}$ and  $ \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{q *n}{p}$, we can deduce that $ \dfrac{p}{q} = \dfrac{q *n}{p}$. I believe the proof is fine up to this part.

Now I claim the following: Since $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, $\frac{p}{q}$ is in lowest terms. Since $p,q,n$ are all positive integers, there must exist some positive integer $r$ such that $p*r = q*n$ and $q *r = p$. (I believe this is the fishy part. Perhaps this can't be justified straight from definition of equivalence classes?).

As such, we know $q*r = p$ or $ r = \dfrac{p}{q} = \sqrt{n} \implies  r^2 = n$. Since $r$ is an integer, $n$ must be a perfect square.

Where did my proof go wrong?

Comment: Your fishy part is indeed wrong. You can only find $r,s\geq 1$ so that $p\cdot r=q\cdot n\cdot s$ and $q\cdot r=p\cdot s$.

Comment: @IanColey even if $\dfrac{p}{q}$ are in lowest terms? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: You have got $p^2=q^2n$.  Show that this implies $q=1$.

Comment: @IanColey I disagree with your comment. If $p/q$ is in lowest terms, the OP's argument is correct.

Comment: @Macavity I understand the standard argument. I'm just wondering why this approach fails. My professor said that it's because it wouldn't be *possible* to prove this without using the unique factorization theorem, but I can't figure out why this approach is incorrect. Perhaps I used the unique factorization theorem without realizing it?

Comment: Right! Without unique factorization we cannot assert that there is a UNIQUE lowest -terms expression. Uniqueness is needed to show that $ r$  exists.

Comment: It is possible to show $\sqrt n\not \in Q$ without using uniqueness of factorization, but it's too long for a comment. It relies on there being a least possible  $p$, if $\sqrt n=p/q,$ and then showing there is a smaller one (contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

> Since $p,q,n$ are all positive integers, there must exist some positive integer $r$ such that $p*r = q*n$

It is only true when $p\leqslant q*n$.

> and $q *r = p$.

It is only true when $p\geqslant q$.

And you didn't the $r$s are the same.